# In Rails controller action, how to get the session object from the cookie?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, controller

In Rails controller action, how to get the session object from the cookie value? Meaning, if I have the cookie value that was sent to the server, and I want to retrieve the relevant session object that corresponds to the cookie value.

Comment: maybe `request.cookies` can help you.
ref: https://gist.github.com/robertsosinski/90619/bb7b77477569db6770361d34bd8d7ed010fb7451

Comment: @hashrocket, the whole session object is an associative array that is attached to the current user (meaning the current session that corresponds to the cookie sent by the user). I am talking about how can I access other sessions that doesn't belong to the current cookie sent by the user.